# Foreach through IEnumerable in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ienumerable

can someone help please, dont know what I am doing wrong:

my viewmodel:

```
public class ScormModuleViewModel
{
  public IEnumerable<ScormModuleInfo> ScormModuleInfo { get; set; }
  public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
  public int PageSize { get; set; }
  public double Total { get; set; }
  public int RecordsPerPage { get; set; }
}
```

then my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page)
{
  List<ScormModuleInfo> modules = new List<ScormModuleInfo>();
  foreach (var directory in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(scormRootDir))
  {
     ScormModuleInfo module = new ScormModuleInfo();
     module.ScormModule = ZincService.ScormService.GetScormModule(scormTitle, scormDirectory);

      if (module.ScormModule != null)
        module.Installed = true;
      else
      {
        module.Installed = false;
        module.ScormModule = new ScormModule();
        module.ScormModule.Directory = scormDirectory;
        module.ScormModule.Title = scormTitle;
      }

      module.ScormModule.EntryPointRef = scormEntryPointRef;
      module.ScormModule.IdentifierRef = scormIdentifierRef;
      module.ScormModule.LaunchHeight = scormLaunchHeight;
      module.ScormModule.LaunchWidth = scormLaunchWidth;
      module.ScormModule.LaunchResize = scormLaunchResize;
      module.ScormModule.RelativeHtmlPath = scormRelativeHtmlPath;
      module.ScormModule.SchemaVersion = scormSchemaVersion;

      if (module.Installed)
      {
        // TODO: Save changes to module
        //ZincService.ScormService.UpdateScormModuleSettings(
      }

      modules.Add(module);
      noOfScormPackages++ ;

    }
  }

  ScormModuleViewModel model = new ScormModuleViewModel();
  model.ScormModuleInfo = modules;
  model.CurrentPage = page.GetValueOrDefault(1);
  model.PageSize = PageSizeSettings.ScormPackages;
  model.Total = noOfScormPackages;

  // Now iterate over modules and read imsmanifest.xml file for details of entry point and resources required.

  return View(model);
 }
```

and my view:

```
 <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<List<Zinc.Web.Areas.Admin.ViewModels.Scorm.ScormModuleViewModel>>" %>

      foreach (var module in Model)
   { %>
 <li>
   <div class="col1">
     <a href='javascript:LoadTrainingModuleWithDedicatedAPIObj("<%= module.ScormModuleInfo.r   .sc.ScormModule.RelativeHtmlPath %>/<%= module.ScormModule.EntryPointRef %>", "<%: module.ScormModule.Title %>", "<%: module.ScormModule.LaunchWidth %>", "<%: module.ScormModule.LaunchHeight %>");'>
       <% if (module.ScormModule.Title.Length < 70)
          { %>
         <%: module.ScormModule.Title%>
       <% }
          else
          { %>
          <%: module.ScormModule.Title.Substring(0, 70)%>....
       <% } %>
     </a>
   </div>
```

i get redlines under all the module. properties?
i dont understand, what am i doing wrong?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

`Model` is your ViewModel. `Model.ScormModuleInfo` is the IEnumerable of `ScormModuleInfo` type.

```
foreach (var module in Model.ScormModuleInfo)
```

In your controller you are passing `ScormModuleViewModel` to view not `List<ScormModuleViewModel>`

So Replace

```
System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<List<Zinc.Web.Areas.Admin.ViewModels.Scorm.ScormModuleViewModel>>
```

To:

```
System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Zinc.Web.Areas.Admin.ViewModels.Scorm.ScormModuleViewModel>
```

Comment: that is what I thought but i dont have it in the intellisense list when I type the . after Model??

Comment: aaaaah did not even see that, takes another pair of eyes! LOL thanks!